# Windows server nginx peak shaving and valley filling configuration

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2012

```
  Windows server, Nginx is configured with load balancing, with 10000 concurrent requests per second for 180 seconds. There will be a large number of requests rejected and not responding. How can Nginx be configured to ensure that all requests can be queued and responded to normally?
```

nginx config

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc55r.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP7zz.png)

Can configuration meet the requirements under Windows?